# Why node.js script is never ending?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following script in node.js:

```
var db = require("redis");
var dbclient = db.createClient();
function doSomeUpload()
        dbclient.zrangs("noper", 0, 5000, function (err, replies){
            var lengthNum = replies.length;
            for (var i=0; i < replies.length; i++){
                // Upload the file with s3 client
                uploader.on('end', function();
                lengthNum--;
                if (lengthNum == 0){
                    console.log("Done!")
                    return;
                }
            })    
})
doSomeUpload()
```

When I run this script: `node scriptupload.js`, `Done!` is printed, but the script never ending. It is still run, and I have to do `ctrl+c` in order to end the node.js process.

Why is it never ending (even when the function returns..)

Comment: What's with the downvotes people? Provide comments or don't downvote. That is particularly bad behavior with new community members.

Comment: There are variables like **uploader** that aren't declared in the code provided and it's unclear which libraries are used.  Having an SSCCE would help immensely. Can you provide an SSCCE? http://sscce.org/

Comment: I understand that you can't include the AWS access key or AWS secret access key.  Just put in blank strings for those if you're not letting the AWS node SDK default load them from **~/.aws/credentials**

Comment: you should accept an answer if we've provided one.  A lot of work went into these answers ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put a `console.log("Returned");` at the end of your script.   It should get called but perhaps one of the S3 uploads is hanging.

Beyond that you have a syntax errors:

1. on line 3 (missing open brace **{** and corresponding closing brace has an closing paren **)** that it shouldn't)
2. on line 9 (semicolon **;** instead of open brace **{** and closing brace following)
3. for loop is missing a closing brace
4. the call to dbclient.zrangs is missing a semicolon **;** after
5. the call to uploader.on is missing a semicolon **;** (may not be necessary but complicates things and the majority Node.js style advocates using them)
6. Missing semicolon **;** after call to **doSomeUpload()**

There is a semantic error or unnecessary code:

1. the return inside the **uploader.on()** callback will return from that callback not break the for loop or return from **doSomeUpload()**

Here is the corrected code with some simplications, naming enhancements, and error handling:

```
var db = require("redis");
var dbclient = db.createClient();
function doSomeUpload(){
    dbclient.zrangs("noper", 0, 5000, function(err, replies){
        if (err){
            console.error(err);
        } else {
            var uploadsRemaining = replies.length;
            replies.forEach(function(reply){
                // Upload the file with s3 client
                uploader.on('end', function() {
                    uploadsRemaining--;
                    if (uploadsRemaining == 0){
                        console.log("Done!");
                    }
                });
            });
         }
    });
}
doSomeUpload();
```

I think the bug is in the code not shared.  The S3 upload may be blocking and this is easily verified by setting a low timeout of say 10 seconds to see.

It is very worthwhile to use JSLint or an editor that builds it or something like it in (Emacs and WebStorm both do):
http://jslint.com/

Run the code through that until it comes up clean.  Make sure to scrub the code (remove credentials or IP sensitive code) before submitting to the online tool.  It's probably better to download the tool and run it locally or use an editor with JavaScript code inspection.

In production your code should have no errors or warnings.  Doing this significantly limits room for confusing runtime behavior.

Comment: @Middleware does this address your problems?

Comment: The thing that helps me is to replace the return with:`process.exit()`

Comment: Don't do that.  That's a hack hiding the real problem.  In production workarounds like exit are cancer to code quality.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is very awkward, you should decrease a counter instead, and first initialize it with the `replies.length`. Otherwise it's easy to get an infinite loop.

Also there is an error on the last line of the for loop, where you pass an empty callback to the uploader's `end` event.
You also missed a couple of semicolons (which are optional, but make the program clear).

```
var db = require("redis");
var dbclient = db.createClient();
function doSomeUpload() {
        dbclient.zrangs("noper", 0, 5000, function (err, replies) {
            for (var i = replies.length; i > 0; i--) {
                // Upload the file with s3 client
                uploader.on('end', function() {});
            }
        });
});

doSomeUpload();
```

Comment: `for (i=0;i<j;i++)` has the same number of iterations as `for(i=j;i>0;i--)` it just recerses the indexing order which is irrelevant here.

Comment: See the part where he forgot to close the callback function

Comment: Yep.  I think I've captured all the syntax errors now.  Does my version of the sybtax fixed code look sensible?

Comment: I can remove the downvote but you need to remove the value judgment on decrementing vs incrementing loops which is neither correct or constructive.

Comment: I'm not saying he doesn't know to code or that I can code better. And I wasn't saying that decrementing is better than incrementing either. I mean that he should put the loop termination condition inside the for condition instead of inside the loop. This way is easier to read and understand, otherwise you would be more error-prone and you could get infinite loops if you're not paying attention. Also my answer could be incomplete, and you could say that in the comment. it isn't wrong by itself to downvote it

Comment: that's fair. It's not what is happening though. The original loop terminates fine.  The **return** inside that uploader.on callback has no effect as it only returns from that specific callback whenever it is asynchronously called.  It's a red herring and I puzzled over it initially as well.

Comment: "Otherwise it will get into an infinite loop" is factually wrong.  That's the main problem and really the major sticking point for my downvote.

Comment: I get what you're saying. I don't believe the downvote should be used like that anyway. I provided an answer that may be incomplete or may not be the solution, but that doesn't mean it's wrong or that you should be downvoting all wrong answers. I can just remove it but I wanted to give the Op an advice at least, even if I didn't solve the problem. And the code won't fit in a comment

Comment: I don't want to discourage you or beat you up here. I'm a bit blunt sometimes ;) My goal is to help everyone here learn and empower them to fix these problems in their software.

Comment: @AlainO'Dea: I said it would be easier to get an error resulting in (eventually) an infinite loop, if the condition isn't clear and you don't pay careful attention

Comment: Yeah I understand that but you're saying to the downvoters not to discourage newcomers. I'm probably not a real rookie on stackoverflow but I've started to help and give answers recently. I know I can do way better myself and improve the answers I provide

Comment: you can edit your answer. Downvotes are intended as correctives for errors. An answer with any false information is one I will downvote and there are many other SO users who do the same.

Comment: There isn't anything false.. Even if there isn't the solution what I said its true

Comment: good point. That's why I always comment with a downvote. The anonymous downvoting is what got me on the OP's question. I actually upvoted it.  The comment allows the recipient of a downvote to address the issue. I've gotten loads of downvotes and sometimes even delete my content if it's appropriate to address the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94930/discussion-between-zorgatone-and-alain-odea).

Comment: I made a big mistake here.  I didn't consider the alternative syntax fix you have provides which makes the loop error correct.

Answer (score -1):

you need to decrease your counter instead of increasing, otherwise it will never be smaller then replies.length:

```
for (var i=replies.length; i > 0; i--){
            // Upload the file with s3 client
            uploader.on('end', function();
            // lengthNum--; // You don't need this anymore
            if (i == 0){
                console.log("Done!")
                return;
            }
        })
```

greetings

Comment: I decrease it.. The function returns. It prints the Done word.

Comment: no you decrease your `lengthNum`, not your counter variable `i`

Comment: But If I will do it, then i will be negative number.

Comment: in my opinion `i` can be replaced with `lengthNum` - you only need one of them

Comment: I don't understand how it will solve the problem. The function returns.. and the for loop is ending.

Comment: and you wanted you loop to end?! `Done! is printed, but the script never ending`

Comment: It should be: var i=replies.length -1; and the script still never ending.I want the the script will wxis witout click on ctrl+c.

Comment: why should it be `var i=replies.length -1`?

Comment: @messerbill the decrementing loop is identical to the original.  This makes no difference.  Think about it and run it your head.  Does it behave differently?

Comment: @Zorgatone I provides an answer and was working on one when I downvoted these incorrect answers. Please remove this comment.

Comment: @messerbill not true.  This code is async.  The last S3 upload may finish faster and print done.  That would be confusing.